# Would a pilot know that one of their crew is armed?

Tags: security, crew, ffdo

The [Federal Flight Deck Officer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Flight_Deck_Officer) page on Wikipedia says this:

> Under the FFDO program, flight crew members are authorized to use firearms. A flight crew member may be a pilot, flight engineer or navigator assigned to the flight.

To me, it seems like this would be crucial information for the PIC to know, if their flight engineer (for example) was armed; but on the flip-side of this, the engineer might want to keep that to himself if he's with a crew he hasn't flown with before.

Is there a guideline on whether an FFDO should inform the crew that he's armed?

Comment: It will become rather apparent when you see the crew member unlock, load and holster their weapon.

Comment: @casey It has to be holstered in a particular place? Otherwise `the engineer might want to keep that to himself`

Comment: You should clarify whether you are asking about FFDO or "not commercial aviation" as FFDO only exist at airlines.

Comment: @casey Ah I see! Let it be commercial then. I'll edit momentarily.

Comment: It has to be briefed as different door procedures will be in effect. Ill figure out what I can or cant say and post an A later.

Comment: This question can't legally be answered by anybody who actually knows the answer and should probably be closed.  I can't find a suitable reason under the close link though.

Comment: @casey Did you manage to figure this out?

Comment: Seriously, we can't answer your question.  I wouldn't even have said as much as casey already did.  It's nothing personal.

Comment: @Ralgha Then post an answer with the reasoning for that, citing a source; this is the first I've heard of it. Btw, you can choose Close > Off-topic > Other if you think the question deserves closing; though I'd respectfully disagree that it's off-topic.

Comment: It's not off-topic, which is why I didn't vote to close it.  It simply can't be answered.

Comment: @DannyBeckett SSI and I won't comment further than I already have.

Comment: @casey Hey, no worries! It was just cos you mentioned...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer to this question is protected as [Sensitive Security Information (SSI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitive_Security_Information) and can't legally be disclosed here.  Anyone who does answer the question either doesn't know what they are talking about, or faces steep legal consequences.

Many, even most, questions relating to airline security (in the US at least ) are similarly handicapped.